# Element Flashing

Tags: javascript, css

Everything works as intended except that optFA-1 flashes briefly when scrolling down. I'm not sure whether this is due to the CSS (I think not), or if a value's not been set appropriately in the JS.

```js
$(function(){
    var lastScrollTop = 0, delta = 5;
    $(window).scroll(function(event){
       var st = $(this).scrollTop();
       if(st === 0) {
            $("#optFA-1").css('visibility','hidden').animate({opacity:0}, 100);
       }
       else{
           if(Math.abs(lastScrollTop - st) <= delta)
              return;
           
           if (st > lastScrollTop){
               // downscroll code
               $("#optFA-1").css('visibility','hidden').css('opacity', 0);
           } else {
              // upscroll code
              $("#optFA-1").css('visibility','visible').css('opacity', 1);
           }
           lastScrollTop = st;
       }
    });
    
});
```

```css
#optFA-1 {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    transition: all 0.3s;
    z-index: 9;
    background: #202020;
}
#optFA-1 img {
 opacity: 1;
    height: 42px;
    width: 60px;
    position: relative;
 }
.optFA-L {
 margin: 15px 0 15px 10px;
    float: left;
    height: 42px;
    width: 60px;
    overflow: hidden;
} 
.optFA-R {
    font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    position: absolute;
    top: 12px;
    line-height: 14px;
    left: 78px;
    right: 21px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <div id="optFA-1">
 <div class="optFA-X"></div>
 <div class="optFA-L"><img src=""></div>
 <div class="optFA-R"><span>Next Up</span><br />Fairies Caught Smoking Crack in Beverly Hills</div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit @Blazemonger. Also this is to run on mobile only.

Comment: I'm trying to replicate your problem but I don't see the blinking you mention: https://jsfiddle.net/wtn69qfj/

Comment: Thanks for trying to replicate, I think I see the problem, it starts with opt-FA1 visible, but I want it to start without it being visible. Was just wondering what best approach would be.

Comment: So maybe simply adding `opacity:0;` to it solves it? https://jsfiddle.net/wtn69qfj/1/

Comment: Thanks @FaustoNA - that worked!

Comment: I'm going to add it as an answer in case you'd like to upvote it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `opacity:0;` to the flashing element in order to set its **default state** to "invisible" like so: https://jsfiddle.net/wtn69qfj/1/

The jQuery will work the same way but the element will appear transparent by default, on page load.